# How to remove 2 or more spaces that are next to each other from a char array

Tags: java, arrays, spaces

```
public static void removeDuplicateSpaces(char[] characters) {

    int dupCount = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        if (characters[i] == ' ' && characters[i + 1] == ' ') {
            dupCount++;
            for (int j = i; j < characters.length - 1; j++) {
                characters[j] = characters[j + 1];

            }
            if ((characters[i] == ' ' && characters[i + 1] == ' ')) {
                dupCount++;
                for (int j = i; j < characters.length - 1; j++) {
                    characters[j] = characters[j + 1];
                }
                dupCount++;
            }
            for (int add = characters.length - 1; add > 
                     characters.length- dupCount; add--) {
                characters[add] = '\u0000';

            }

        }

    }

}
```

I need to reduce all sequences of 2 or more spaces to 1 space within the 
      characters array. If any spaces are removed then the same number
     of Null character '\u0000' will fill the elements at the end of the
     array.
My code does not remove 4 spaces when there are 5 spaces in between.
Such as {'e','','','','','','4'}

Answer (score 2):

How about converting it to `String`, doing some regex and back to char array?

```
new String(characters).replaceAll("[ ]+", " ").toCharArray()
```

EDIT: Ok, I see you're actually not returning the array, but modifying the original array. Then you could use a simple loop

```
String s = new String(characters).replaceAll("[ ]+", " ");
for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
    characters[i] = (i < s.length() ? s.charAt(i) : '\u0000');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

different variant, to show you how it should work with simple loops:

```
public static void removeDuplicateSpaces(final char[] characters) {
    for (int i = 0; i < characters.length; i++) {
        while (characters[i] == ' ') { // while current symbol is space
            for (int j = (i + 1); j < characters.length; j++)
                characters[j - 1] = characters[j]; // shift the rest of array
            characters[characters.length - 1] = 0;
        }
    }
}
```